# Call JS function with controller function on click

Tags: database, javascript, redirect

I want to do to tasks simultaneously on the click of button.

1. Insert the details into database.
2. redirect to checkout.

I have redirected to checkout using java script but I am not being able to enter details in database.

Comment: before redirecting you need to perform database save operation

Comment: @programmer_rkt Is it possible with js?

Comment: If it is a form you can specify `action` to a custom controller and then perform database save operation and then redirecting operation in that controller.

Comment: If you depend on using JS, Ajax is the way to go. If you could provide the code that you have tried, we can correct it and show you the way to a working solution. But the question "as is" is not a good SE question imho.